# Removing Trusted software providers from 'Software & Updates'

Tags: ppa

The PPA didn't work so using 'Software and Updates' I removed its entry under the 'Other Software' Tab. However, under the 'Authentication' tab, it is still listed as a Trusted software provider. I clicked remove and entered my password but it is still on the list. Please help.

Comment: Please post a screenshot/error to your corresponding ppa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this time you can rely to terminal for list current trusted software provider, by:

```
sudo apt-key list
```

Now find your key that you want to remove, when you finish searching, run following command:

```
sudo apt-key del (keyid)
```

Where `(keyid)` is the actual keyid of your corresponding trusted software providers.

**For example:**

```
Liso@thinkpad:~$ apt-key list    
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nowrep-qupzilla.gpg
------------------------------------------
pub   1024R/7A2DA9DB 2011-12-05
uid                  Launchpad PPA for David Rosca

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ppsspp-stable.gpg
----------------------------------------
pub   4096R/ED0F784C 2014-08-02
uid                  Launchpad PPA for PPSSPP
Liso@thinkpad:~$ sudo apt-key del ED0F784C
[sudo] password for Liso: 
OK
```

Will delete PPSSPP key.

Comment: I get the same response from apt-key del but the apt I selected to delete does not go away just as when I try to remove it with software sources. Seems like a bug I guess?

Comment: Some keys look a bit different. For example:
pub rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374 2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

The keyid is '8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374 2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092'

Comment: Like @zorkerz said some keys look different. In Ubuntu 18.04 I used `$ sudo apt-key del "68AE AE71 F9FA 1587 03C1  CBBC 8D04 CE49 EFB2 0B23"` to remove the key of a trusted software provider.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution :

To list the keys use

```
sudo apt-key list
```

You will get something like

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      **** **** **** **** ****  **** **** **** **** 
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      **** **** **** **** ****  **** **** **** **** 
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012)
```

And delete by

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
```